# Running into error `Error: Cannot find module` when using dynamic imports (React.Suspense)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dynamic-import

I'm running into a strange error when using dynamic imports.

I've created a reproducible repository and a Sandbox (links below).

What is odd is that the Sandbox works just fine, but the code in the repo falls apart -- with the exact same code.

It's a simple `npx create-react-app` with the following content:

```
// App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import MySuspense from './MySuspense';

export default function App() {
    return <MySuspense importPath={'@material-ui/icons/DoneAll'} />;
}
```

```
// MySuspense.tsx
import React from 'react';

type TSuspense = {
    importPath: string;
};
const MySuspense = React.memo(({ importPath }: TSuspense) => {
    const Component = React.lazy(() => import(importPath));

    return (
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div />}>
            <Component />
        </React.Suspense>
    );
});

export default MySuspense;
```

This throws an error,

```sh
Error: Cannot find module '@material-ui/icons/DoneAll'
```

---

I have lint running as well, and it's giving me a warning,

```sh
./src/MySuspense.tsx
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

But if I do,

```
const Component = React.lazy(() => import(`${path}`));
// instead of const Component = React.lazy(() => import(path));
```

Then the lint warning goes away.

---

If I, instead of passing the path as a prop, hardcode the import path, then it works:

```
const MySuspense = React.memo(({ importPath }: TSuspense) => {
    const Component = React.lazy(() => import('@material-ui/icons/DoneAll'));

    return (
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div />}>
            <Component />
        </React.Suspense>
    );
});
```

But that defeats the whole purpose of dynamic imports.

The EXACT same code running in a Sandbox works just fine. I've been pulling my hair out for hours.

I've tried adding a `.babelrc` as documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import), but that didn't work,

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "esnext"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

What could be wrong here? I've cloned the repo onto 3 different machines and I get the same error. How is the Sandbox any different, why would the code work there? Is there something crucial in some configuration that I'm missing or am I just going crazy here?

Honestly, any help wod be appreciated at this point, I've tried everything that I could think of at this point.

[Github repo](https://github.com/mkhoussid/test_dynamic_imports)

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-khayyam-8ljvr?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: don't you need `import(importPath).then(m => m.Component)`?

Comment: Not with [React.lazy()](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)